# How can i force the imagemagick module of nodejs to output one single image only?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, node-imagemagick

I am using the imagemagick module with Nodejs

```
im  = require('imagemagick');
```

The imagemagick module uses the imagemagick command line tools.
I use the  convert method to crop an image

```
im.convert([image_path, '-crop', '200x150', '-gravity', 'center', target_path],
  function(err, stdout){}
);
```

This results in two images. The one with the cropped image area - the second with the image garbage i tried to get rid of.

**How can i force imagemagick to output one image file only?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) for cropping, which is admittedly a little obtuse (emphasis added):

> The width and height of the geometry argument give the size of the image that remains after cropping, **and x and y in the offset (if present) gives the location of the top left corner of the cropped image with respect to the original image**.
>
> ...
>
> **If the x and y offsets are present, a single image is generated**, consisting of the pixels from the cropping region.
>
> ...
>
> **If the x and y offsets are omitted, a set of tiles of the specified geometry, covering the entire input image, is generated.**

... so, you just need to specify your `x` and `y` offsets as part of your geometry argument, like so: `200x150-100-75`

Notice that I've specified `-100` and `-75` for the upper left corner of your crop region, this is because you set your `gravity` to `center`, but it appears that imagemagick tries to intelligently determine the appropriate distance target based on your gravity, and I don't see exactly how it behaves when you choose `center`. So you may have to play around with this one a bit, or you could omit the `gravity` and use the actual offset from the top left corner of your original image.

Comment: +1 for the quote. i thought gravity-center would center the image and crop the area from the middle of the image

Comment: Yeah, it just seems they got a little feature-happy with the `crop` command, where most people would expect it to automatically discard anything not in the specified area, they keep it unless you specify the offset.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the `+delete` parameter to remove the last image from the image sequence.

```
im.convert([image_file.path, '-crop', geometry, '+delete', thumb_path], ...
```